# Converting relative address to absolute address using HttpClient in java

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I get the web page content by passing URL to HttpGet() method.
This page content will be having relative paths of images,javascripts, href etc.
I have written a custom code where I am finding relative address and get the corresponding absolute address and using replace function I convert all the relative address of web page content to absolute address.But,it results in performance issue.
I am looking for a functionality that converts all relative address to absolute address of a web page at once without using my custom code.

Comment: Some code showcase will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Hi Imran Here is the code..public Str cntToAbPa(String pgeCot,.){
reURL=href.attr(reKey).toStr();    
abURL=href.attr(abKey).toStr();
reURL="\""+reURL+"\"";
abURL="\""+abURL+"\"";
if(!reURL.eqls("/content/")&&!reURL.eqls("#")&&!reURL.eqls("/")&&!reURL.isEmpty()&&!abURL.isEmpty()&&!relativeURL.equalsIgnoreCase(absoluteURL)&&!absoluteURLList.contains(relativeURL)){  
pgeCont=pgeCont.replace(reURL, abURL);}
else if(reURL.equals("/")){
pgeCont=pgeCont.replaceAll("href=\"/\"",href.attr(abKey));
abURLL.add(reURL);}
pgeCont=cntToAbPa(pgeCot,stySht,"href","abs:href"); 
likewe have ima,jscript etc

Comment: In above code  I made all shortcuts because Stackoverflow wont take  entire code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an html `base` tag, then all relative pathes in your document will be applied to this url

```
<head>
  <base href="http://domain.com/foo" />
</head>
<body>
  <img src="images/icon.png" />
</body>
```

This will load `<img src="http://domain.com/foo/images/icon.png"/>`